# PHP random string function preventing duplicate outputs when called multiple times

Tags: php

The following function will create a random string output what is the best way to prevent duplicate outputs / collisions if called multiple times.

```
function random_string($length) {
            $key = '';
            $keys = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'), array('_'));

            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
            }

            return $key;
        }
echo "First : " . random_string(rand(3, 50));
//These have a small percentage of a chance of matching the previous random output lets eliminate all possibility of getting the same output.
echo "Second : " . random_string(rand(3, 50));
echo "Third : " . random_string(rand(3, 50));
echo "Fourth : " . random_string(rand(3, 50));
```

I did read on the PHP documentation that array_unique could achieve what i want but would it be the best solution or is there a more efficient way.

Comment: `Array_unique` will eliminate not unique elements, so instead of 4 strings you will get three or two or even one.

Comment: Store all previously created strings in a collection and loop until your method creates one that isn't included yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
// array to store required strings
$stringsCollection = [];
// 4 is the number of strings that you need
while (sizeof($stringsCollection) != 4) {
    // generate new string
    $randString = random_string($length);
    // if string is not in `stringsCollection` - add it as a key
    if (!isset($stringsCollection[$randString])) {
        $stringsCollection[$randString] = 1;
    }
}
print_r(array_keys($stringsCollection));
```

Answer (score 1):

> or is there a more efficient way

You are heading to "overengeneering land", trying to fix things you cannot even name :) Is it slow? Sluggish? Then profile and fix relevant parts. "Efficient" is buzzword w/o defining what efficiency means for you.

> what is the best way to prevent duplicate outputs / collisions if called multiple times

First, I'd use hashing functions with detailed (i.e. seconds or millis) timestamp + some mt_rand as input like instead. It's limited in length but you can call it multiple times and concatenate results (+ trim if needed). And if you want to be 1000% the value was never returned before, you must keep track of them, however you most likely can **assume** this is not going to happen if you will have input string long enough